# How can I call a jieclass instance in the function decorated by njit?

Tags: python, numba

```
from numba import njit, float64
from numba.experimental import jitclass

@jitclass([('size', float64)])
class Bag(object):
    def __init__(self, size):
        self.size = size

bag = Bag(6.6)

@njit
def getsize():
    print(bag.size)

getsize()
```

Program error: Failed in nopython mode pipeline (step: native lowering)

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that `bag` is a global from `getsize` and this is waht cause the problem. AFAIK, jitclass objects are not yet supported in this context. This can be fixed by passing the object in parameter. Note that accessing global variable is generally slower than local variable and it is also considered as a bad practice in software engineering (unless the value is a constant). Here is an example:

```py
from numba import njit, float64
from numba.experimental import jitclass

@jitclass([('size', float64)])
class Bag(object):
    def __init__(self, size):
        self.size = size

bag = Bag(6.6)

@njit
def getsize(bag):
    print(bag.size)

getsize(bag)
```

Note that jitclass are still an *experimental* feature so it has a limited support so far (as the import explicitly point out).

Comment: Ok thank you, this is the method I have been using before, but recently I want to solve this problem, because it is bloated to pass variables in many functions

Comment: The usual way to solve this in software engineering is to use a "Context" class/structure containing the required values. Global variables make the data flow less clear and often make much harder optimizations including parallelization. It cause hidden side effects that tends to increase the number of bugs due to a kind of "spooky action at a distance". One regular issue is that when the code becomes big, you cannot tell which function change with variable without looking the implementation but for large code this is tedious to do. Not to mention debugging tends also to be harder with them.

Comment: Note that there are related bugs like [this](https://github.com/numba/numba/issues/2501) which I do not expect to be solved any time soon.